# Write custom metadata to Parquet file in Julia

Tags: julia, metadata, parquet

I am currently storing the output (a Julia Dataframe) of my Julia simulation in a Parquet file using `Parquet.jl`. I would also like to save some of the simulation parameters (eg. a list of (byte-)strings) to that same output file.

Preferably, these parameters are different for each column as each column is the result of different starting conditions of my code. However, I could also work with a global parameter list and then untangle it afterwards by indexing.

I have found a solution for Python using `pyarrow`

https://mungingdata.com/pyarrow/arbitrary-metadata-parquet-table/.

Do you know a way how to do it in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite done yet, and it's not registered, but my rewrite of the Julia parquet package, [Parquet2.jl](https://gitlab.com/ExpandingMan/Parquet2.jl) does support both custom file metadata and individual column metadata (the keyword arguments `metadata` and `column_metadata` in `Parquet2.writefile`.

I haven't gotten to documentation for writing yet, but if you are feeling adventurous you can give it a shot.  I do expect to finish up this package and register it within the next couple of weeks.  I don't have unit tests in for writing yet, so of course, if you try it and have problems, please open an issue.

It's probably also worth mentioning that the main use case I recommend for parquet is if you *must* have parquet for compatibility reasons.  Most of the time, Julia users are probably better off with [Arrow.jl](https://github.com/apache/arrow-julia) as the format has a number of advantages over parquet for most use cases, please see [my FAQ answer on this](https://expandingman.gitlab.io/Parquet2.jl/faq/#Which-format-should-I-use?).  Of course, the reason I undertook writing the package is because parquet is arguably the only ubiquitous binary format in "big data world" so a robust writer is desperately needed.